# how to calculate font ascenders and descenders in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, typography, font-design

I am trying to position text at the top-left corner of a canvas in Adobe Photoshop by setting its x and y coordinates to 0. However, due to the font's ascenders, the text is not aligned to the top-left corner as intended. I currently have to manually adjust the text's position. **Is there a way to calculate the ascenders and descenders for a specific font and font size with any programming language, to aid in accurate text placement?**

With x=0. y=0
[image]

Adjustment x= -4, y=-15
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know that in Pillow you can set the anchor to be left top rather than left ascender, and you can also calculate the exact bounding box of the text and place it according to that, but idk about Photoshop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).